# Share in-memory database between processes sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, multiprocessing

It is possible [in any way, even poorly hacked solution] to share in-memory database between many processes? My application has one process that opens the in-memory database and the other are running only `SELECT` queries on the database.

**NOTE:** I need solution only for python 2.7, and btw if it matters the module I use for making new processes is `multiprocessing`.

Comment: So you saying there is no way to do that in SQLite? it might be big headache to move to another db because I have already writtten whole program based on that.

Comment: If you've written the program in a sensible way, it should be easy to switch to another SQL-based DB that uses the Python DB API.

Comment: Why are you using `multiprocessing` and not threads?

Comment: Because I find out that multiprocessing fit more than threads in my application.

Comment: [Have you tried this on UNIX. Hope to help you out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391381/how-to-pass-a-sqlite-connection-object-through-multiprocessing/37483250#37483250)

Answer (score 4):

On Linux you can just use `/dev/shm` as the file location of your sqlite.

This is a memory mounted drive suitable exactly for that.

Comment: @johnedoe_asking do you solve your problem by using this answer?