# shared between processes in-memory sqlite db in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there a way to share an in-memory sqlite database between two different python processes?
I have looked around and while it can be done within the same process (using a connection string like `sqlite3.connect("file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared", uri=True)` for example), it is not clear to me whether (and how) this is possible between processes.

I am using Windows and Python 3.8. Btw for linux it looks a possible work-around is using a memory mounted drive, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39020351/5431734).

Comment: Why not using a file-based db? I suppose you can use memory mapping, if necessary.